# Can we search on Stack Overflow based on or condition over tags?

Tags: discussion, support, search, tag-search

I can search through tags using `[tag-name]` and then add a search term that I want to search like. For multiple tags I can also search with `[tag-name-1][tag-name-2][tag-name-3]`. But it filters the questions by joining the tags using `AND` conditions. So if a question has all the tags then it will come in the result set, otherwise not.

However I want to search the questions based on joining the tags by `OR` conditions. Like I want to filter the questions which either came in PHP or Java.

Is it possible to search like that on Stack Overflow...?

Comment: If it is only for SO, please ask it in MSO.

Comment: @Sagar - read the question. An answer would be valid to all sites. Don't be so quick to direct people away.

Comment: [Cross posted to Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351206).